# C# using: constructor in a different method

Tags: c#, using

All online examples I can find for C#'s `using` instantiate directly within the using parentheses:

```
using (var cnx = new SqlConnection()) { }
```

I would think that the following should act identically, but I still seem to have locked resources:

```
SqlConnection GetConnection() { return new SqlConnection(); }
void foo()
{
    using (var cnx = GetConnection()) { }
}
```

When I step through my program and get to the line following the using's closing brace, I'd expect to be able to alter the db any way I want using SQL Server Management Studio, but I can't. When I close my app, the errors go away.

This isn't segregated to SQL; I've also experienced this with opening file steams in this way. That is: step past the `using` block but the OS won't allow an external app to alter the file.

Am I violating some part of the `using` contract?

Comment: You expect to alter the connection which was already disposed?

Comment: No, I think OP is saying that even after the using section ends (and the connection should have been disposed) the database is still locked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's absolutely fine to use a method which returns the appropriate resource. In particular, this is pretty common:

```
using (var writer = File.CreateText(path))
{
}
```

(and similar methods in `File`).

Basically, this isn't to do with calling a method or calling a constructor - there must be something else wrong. If you can create a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem (ideally with files instead of a database) then we're likely to be able to help you find out what *is* the problem, not just what isn't :)

Answer (score 3):

If you have connection pooling enabled, 'Dispose' wont necessarily physically close the connection.

Comment: Yeah, there is nothing wrong with way the OP is using `using`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using that sort of code all the time:

```
SqlConnection GetConnection() 
{ 
    return new SqlConnection(); 
}

void foo()
{
    using (var cnx = GetConnection()) 
    { 
        cnx.Open();
    }
}
```

If you really want to be sure, call `cnx.Close();` before the closing bracket. However, this was never necessary in my case as the call to `Dispose` automatically closes the connection.